# Signedness of int in while comparing with string.size() showing warning

Tags: c++

So, i was writing down this code

```
void shortened(string s){
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size()-1;++i){
        cnt++;
    }
    //some extra code
}
```

this for loop showed me a warning and i.e. of comparison of integer expressions of different signedness int and string::size_type. But as soon as I changed int i = 0 to unsigned int i=0 there was no warning. I know that the length of the string can never be zero and that's why the warning was shown because int i can hold negative numbers as well. But why the warning was being shown in the first place?

```
 i-0;i<s.size()-1
```

in itself was very complete. I need to clear my doubt.

Comment: "_I know that the length of the string can never be zero_" Sure it can. `std::string s; std::cout << s.size();` would print `0`.

Comment: well a string was passed to shortened all the time. So it can't be 0. Correct me if I am going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Your given code doesn't shows any warning or minimal reproducible error on GDB Compiler. Show us those more code, will be better to find out the error.

Comment: @DrkEthics Compiler can't know this. It is possible, that you would call it in following way: `std::string s; shortened (s);`. Which would result in `s.size()` returning `0`.

Comment: `for (std::size_t i = 1; i < s.size(); ++i)`. If you need the value of `i`, use `i - 1`. The warning comes from the comparison of signed `i` and unsigned `size()`. Such comparisons can lead to subtle bugs, that's why the compiler warns you.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I guess you are right, because I ran the same code on some other compilers and no warning was shown. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Warnings can be shown for any reason whatsoever, or without one. The compiler authors though this practice is generally dubious, so they warn about it. It costs nothing to fix the warning, just change the type to `unsigned` and be done with it.

Comment: @DrkEthics "_I guess you are right, because I ran the same code on some other compilers and no warning was shown._" Did you enable warnings on those, other, compilers. Some have default level of warnings, that is shown, others don't show any warnings unless you, explicitly, enable them. I personally view warnings as "bugs ready to happen", and fix them, as if they were errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are using `g++` as compiler. (`gcc` is the same while `clang` is unfamiliar to me)

This warning comes from the compilation option `-Wall` which asks the compiler to give you detailed warning for everything( `Wall` = `Warning All`). （For more information, you can visit https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options）

So `g++ -o tmp  tmp.cpp` won't show such warning but `g++ -o tmp -Wall tmp.cpp` will.

Come back to the main topic: such a wired warning is shown due to the return type for `string.size()` is `size_t` and `size_t` is one of the unsigned types.

On my machine, I find `size_t` is defined in `stddef.h` as followed:

```
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
```

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

You compare between an `int` and an `unsigned int` in `for` statement and this why here is such a warning.